# Android: How can I convert a receipt to a pdf file?

Tags: android, file, itext, android-pdf-api

I want to make an receipt in pdf file, like the below image, in android programmatically? The following is an example of a printed receipt, please help.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use **itext**.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/

You can find a good eBook in itext library here:
https://www.manning.com/books/itext-in-action-second-edition and if you want free books, take a look at [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) and [ZUGFeRD: The Future of Invoicing](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ZUGFeRD.html) (the ZUGFeRD book explains how to create invoices, which is very similar to creating receipts).

And a good tutorial (**vogella**) can be found here:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPDF/article.html

Alternatively, you can try **APW Library**
http://sourceforge.net/projects/apwlibrary/

Comment: I like the fact that you linked to my book dating from 2010, but I also added some links to more recent books that are available for free.